# Can I restore deleted live templates in Resharper

Tags: resharper

I accidentally deleted some live templates from the live template editor in Reharper and I don't know how to restore them. 
right now, not even the visual studio ones work. 
for example, I accidentally deleted the 'if' live template and when I type if and hit tab I get '`if ()|`' which is not the default VS snippet '`if (true) {...}`'

can someone please let me know how to restore the deleted ones or at least how to activate the default VS snippets.

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out-of-the-box templates can't be deleted completely, they are just marked as "invisible". Open `%AppData%\JetBrains\Shared\vAny\GlobalSettingsStorage.DotSettings` file, look for and remove a similar record:

```
<s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=2309729714BBB04EB920AA915E5D0401/@KeyIndexDefined">False</s:Boolean>
```